# NoneType' object has no attribute 'all

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I try to split the df_combo-dataframe into train and test data

```
sample = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ranji/Downloads/facebook-recruiting-iv-human-or-bot/sampleSubmission.csv')
test_dat = df_combo[df_combo.bidder_id.isin(sample.bidder_id)]
print (sample.bidder_id.values==test_dat['bidder_id'].values).all()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `all()` on the return value of `print()`?

Comment: ....yeah...just don't do that!

Comment: `print()` doesn't return a value, so you can't call methods on it

Answer (score 3):

The `()` after the `print` is being taken as a function call, probably because you are using python 3.  The return of `print` is `None`.

## python2

Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 12 2017, 19:49:36)

```
>>> print (1) + 2
3
```

## python3

Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 21 2019, 16:25:05)

```
>>> print (1) + 2
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```